# Rendering issue with hidden div

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have an issue about values that are correct in my component but wrong when i display a hidden div. I suggets a rendering issue but I failed finding the solution

My component (code is below in my post) is called inside a map from a client parent component. The issue is, when i click on the button to display the modal, no matter what button, my modal display value from the first element of the map:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you see above, i clicked on the third element "toKeep 2" with the index 2 visible under the cross. But, the 0 dipslayed in the modal is supposed to be the same index.

Here is a code sample:

```
export default function DeleteClientComponent({getClients, id, idx}: {getClients: () => Promise<void>, id: string, idx: number}) {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [savedID, setID] = useState("");
  
    function displayDeleteClientModal() {        
        console.log("display: ", savedID);
        console.log("display: ", id); // Those logs diplay correct value
        
        let modal = document.getElementById("my-modal") as HTMLElement;
        
        modal.style.display = 'block'
    }

    const deleteClient = async () => {
        console.log("delete: ", savedID);
        console.log("delete: ", id);
        console.log("delete: ", idx); // All those log display wrong values
    }

    function cancelModal() {
        console.log("cancel: ", savedID);
        console.log("cancel: ", id); // Those logs display wrong values
        let modal = document.getElementById("my-modal") as HTMLElement;

        modal.style.display = 'none'
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(id) // correct value
        setID(id)
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="w-full flex justify-end">
                <button type="button" className='' onClick={displayDeleteClientModal}>X</button>
            </div>

            <p>{idx}</p> {/* This p tag display the correct value visible in the screenshot */}
            {/* modal */}
            <div id="my-modal"
                className="fixed hidden inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-50 overflow-y-auto h-full w-full">
                <div
                className="relative top-20 mx-auto p-5 border w-96 shadow-lg rounded-md bg-white">
                    <div className="text-center">
                        <h3 className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Are you sure to delete this client ?</h3>
                        <p className="text-gray-900">{idx}</p> {/* The 0 displayed in my modal */}
                    </div>
                    <div className="items-center px-4 py-3 flex gap-6">

                        <button id="ok-btn" onClick={() => deleteClient()}
                            className="px-4 py-2 bg-green-500 text-white text-base font-medium rounded-md w-full shadow-sm hover:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-300">
                            CONFIRM
                        </button>
                        <button id="cancel-btn" onClick={cancelModal}
                            className="px-4 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white text-base font-medium rounded-md w-full shadow-sm hover:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-300">
                            CANCEL
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I put in comment what log is correct or no.

We can see that value displayed in my browser, in useEffect and displayDeleteClientModal are correct, but when the modal appear, values in the modal, delete and cancel have the value of the first element. I noticed if I put my modal in display block at the begining, I have the good values so I think the problem come from something about rendering

**EDIT**
The parent:

```
export default function LateralNav() {
  interface singleClient {
    client: string,
    id: string
  }

  const [clients, setClients] = useState<Array<singleClient>>([]);

  async function getClients() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/client', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      setClients(await response.json())
    } catch {
      console.log("error");
    } finally {
    }         
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getClients()
  }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {
              clients.length > 0 ? (
                clients.map((client, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={index} className='grid gap-4 grid-cols-client'>
                      <Link href={`/client/${encodeURIComponent(client.client)}`}>
                        <div className='mb-0.5 py-0.5 px-2 bg-slate-800 hover:bg-slate-600 hover:font-bold'>
                          <p>{client.client} - {index}</p>
                        </div>
                      </Link>
                      {client.id.length > 0 && (<DeleteClientComponent getClients={getClients} id={client.id} idx={index} />)}
                    </div>
                  )
                })
              ) : (
                <p>No item available</p>
              )
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

The parent component
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OfHR.png

Comment: Share the component where you are calling DeleteClientComponent

Comment: in my opinion it should work, can you add a `console.log(idx)` below of `const [savedID, setID] = useState("");`

Comment: i also would remove ```useEffect(() => {
        console.log(id) // correct value
        setID(id)
    })
```

it make no sense 
also remove 

```const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [savedID, setID] = useState("");```

Comment: I tried what you asked @StefanSchulz, same behavior I still have the issue

Comment: Additional information, even when i move content from the child component to the parent one I have the same issue. So the problem isn't about how the data is sent from one component to the other but about how Nextjs manage the data with element that are hidden at the render

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer but I don't have technical explanation to give. From what I understand, it's about how NextJS manage rendering with hidden element.

Instead of using "display: hidden", I set a condition that depend of a value managed with setState:

The parent component:

```
interface singleClient {
  client: string,
  id: string
}

interface Clients {
  clients: singleClient[]
}

export default function LateralNav(clients: Clients) { 
  const [clientsList, setClients] = useState<Array<singleClient>>([]);
  const [modalFlag, setModalFlag] = useState<Boolean>(false);
  const [clientId, setID] = useState<string>("");
  const [clientName, setName] = useState<string>("");

  async function getClients() {
    setModalFlag(false)
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/client', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      setClients(await response.json())
    } catch {
      console.log("error");
      
    } finally {
    }       
  }

  function displayDeleteClientModal(index: number) {
    setModalflag(true)
    setID(clientsList[index].id)
    setName(clientsList[index].client)
  }

  function cancelModal() {
    setModalFlag(false)
  }

  const deleteClient = async (id: string) => {
    console.log(clientId);
    
    try {  
      await fetch(`/api/client/${clientId}`, {
          method: 'DELETE',
          headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
      });
      getClients()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {            
      cancelModal()
    }
}

  useEffect(() => {
    setModalFlag(false)
    setClients(clients.clients)
  }, [])

  return (
      <div>
          <Image alt='cli3nt-logo' id="image" src="/cli3nts_green.png" width={264} height={64} className='mb-6 hidden md:block'/>            
          { 
            
            clientsList.length > 0 ? (
              clientsList.map((client, index) => {                  
                return (
                  <div key={index} className='grid gap-4 grid-cols-client'>
                    <Link href={`/client/${encodeURIComponent(client.client)}`}>
                        <div className='mb-0.5 py-0.5 px-2 bg-slate-800 hover:bg-slate-600 hover:font-bold'>
                          <p>{client.client}</p>
                        </div>
                      </Link>
                      <div className="w-full flex justify-end">
                        <button type="button" className='oui' onClick={() => displayDeleteClientModal(index)}>X</button>
                      </div>
                      {
                        modalFlag && <DeleteModalComponent getClients={getClients} deleteClient={deleteClient} cancelModal={cancelModal} id={clientName}/>
                      }
                  </div>
                )
              })
            ) : (
              <div>
                <p>No item available</p>
              </div>
            )
          }
      </div>
  )
}
```

I moved my button to the parent component and i placed only the modal in a child component. By doing this, i can manage some value from the parent directly. Managing the conditional rendering with **setModalFlag**, getting the clientName and the clientID.

Displaying my modal with a condition in the render and not with display: hidden/block fixed my issue

Thanks for the help !